# Document Library Not Returning Correct Search Results

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, search-results, enterprise-search

Created a document library, but the search bar isn't returning the correct results.  It returns some of the items, but also includes other items that have nothing to do with what was put into the search bar.  Reindexed and it still doesn't work.

As possible solutions I thought about creating a Search Center not sure if this is the best route.  Is anyone familiar with this issue and what I can do to solve the issue?

Comment: Are you using custom columns?

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis Yes, I am using custom columns.

Comment: After you create a library, add an item, run a full crawl so that the crawled properties are created, then create managed properties for and map them to the crawled properties. Run full crawl again and all should be fine. All this is a one time action on a new farm.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the items has nothing to do with what has been put in the search box? Keep in mind that SP search also includes the actual document contents in the search index for known file types